# Trigger Sql Sever

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Tengo una base de datos con dos tablas: Categoría y Equipo, la relación entre las tablas va así: una categoría puede tener muchos equipos. He creado un trigger para que en el momento de insertar un equipo un campo cantidad de la tabla categoría se sume a 1. El trigger va así:

```
create trigger Actualizar
on equipo for insert
as
update categoria set cantidad = cantidad + 1
from categoria, equipo
where categoria.id = equipo.categoria;
```

Al primer equipo funciona bien aumenta 1, pero en el momento de insertar otro equipo con categoría diferente, la cantidad aumenta en 1 tanto para el nuevo como para el anterior.

Answer (score 3):

El trigger esta actualizando todos los registros, ya que el where no esta filtrando, mas bien esta actuando como un JOIN. Para obtener el `id` del registro insertado, se tiene que consultar a `inserted`

Te dejo el trigger completo para que lo veas

```
CREATE TRIGGER Actualizar ON equipo FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    declare @id int;
    set @id = (select categoria from inserted);
    update categoria set cantidad = cantidad + 1
    where id = @id
END
```

Comment: Me salió perfecto, muchas gracias.